# How do I get the values from multiple forms after a POST in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have several forms (select choice form) in the same html page, for each row. Suppose the choices are `EDIT`, `UPDATE`, `ADD`, if there are 5 rows, and user chooses `UPDATE` for two of the rows, and then click `Submit`, my view will process the request.

To process this request, I need a list of selected choices:

```
 [{'row1':'UPDATE', 'row2': 'UPDATE'}]   (okay... I need to be able to distinguish which choice belongs to which row...)
```

Let say this is my html file.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>{{ form.as_p}}</td>
   <td> 121 </td>
</tr>
   <td>{{ form.as_p}}</td>
   <td> 212 </td>
</table>

<form action='' method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" name="Submit!"></input>
</form>
```

When it renders, we have this

```
<td><p><label for="id_choice_field">Choice field:</label> <select name="choice_field" id="id_choice_field">
<option value="value1">First</option>
<option value="value2">Second</option>
</select></p></td>
<td> 212 </td>
</table>
<form action='' method="POST"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='41f4aa9cc46e3e21bb46c99bc992973a' /></div> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit!"></input>
</form>
```

I tried

```
e = request.POST.getlist('choice_field')
return HttpResponse(e)
```

it gives me a blank page, so there is nothing.....

How do I get a list of selected values from the whole table (and it's associated data, like row #)?

Thank you.

---

Final code

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from forms import MyForm
from django.core.context_processors import csrf 

def my_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        e = request.POST.getlist("choice_field")

        return HttpResponse(e)
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    c = {'form':form}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('hello.html', c)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

CHOICES = (('value1', 'First',),('value2', 'Second',))

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

**hello.html**

```
<form action='' method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
   <td>{{ form.as_p}}</td>
   <td> 121 </td>
</tr>
   <td>{{ form.as_p}}</td>
   <td> 212 </td>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data fields are out side of form tag that is why you are getting nothing from `POST`. Put your data fields inside form tag as:

```
<form action='' method="POST"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='41f4aa9cc46e3e21bb46c99bc992973a' /></div>

<table>
<tr>
   <td>{{ form.as_p}}</td>
   <td> 121 </td>
</tr>
   <td>{{ form.as_p}}</td>
   <td> 212 </td>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="Submit!"></input>
</form>
```